# ufw exclude internal IPs from logs

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have a test HTTPS server running on Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04.4) on port 20000. I would like to log all connections on this port. So I did this, and it works fine.

```
ufw allow log-all 20000/tcp
```

Now, I would like to exclude any local IP connections from logs related to this rule. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Not sure if this is the recommended way to do it, but I inserted another rule above the "log-all" rule.

```
sudo ufw insert 4 allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 20000 proto tcp
```

This rule doesn't do any extra logging, and since it is before the other one all the local IPs allow connection with no logs. So, here's what my rules look like now

```
To                    Action              From
---                   ------              -----
....
20000/tcp            ALLOW IN           192.168.1.0/24
20000/tcp            ALLOW IN           Anywhere           (log-all)
....
```